# unknown nodes in network

Tags: ip-routing

When I look at my routing table, I notice two ip addresses within my local network that I am not sure where they are coming from. I currently only have one computer connected to my router, which has a LAN address of 192.168.2.6. Here's the output on Ubuntu:

```
route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

192.168.2.1 is the default gateway as represented by the G flag, but what could possibly be 169.254.0.0  and  192.168.2.0? I have no printers, nothing else with an IP except my computer on 192.168.2.6 and the default gateway (my router) on 192.168.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those aren't nodes, they're networks (the subnet your device's address is in `192.168.2.0/24`, and the automatic private range `169.254.0.0/16`).

You're never going to see a specific node aside from routers in your route list, and those are only in there because they're connected routes (the default gateway won't be used for connections to those addresses).

Are you maybe thinking of the ARP table, which would have entries for other devices in your subnet?

Comment: yes the output of the arp command is what I was thinking this was. And I was actually reading a lot about arp today.